# Batch file to Check and Compare size of .log file in a folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, automation

I have to find the files from a folder whose size is greater than 10 MB.

Please guide how can i complete this task.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

List all files greater than 10MB in a given directory and its subdirectories.

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "SEARCH_DIR=%~1"

echo Usage: %~nx0 directory
echo Lists all files in given directory and its subdirectories larger than 10MB.

if not exist "%SEARCH_DIR%" (
    echo "%SEARCH_DIR%" does not exist.
    exit /b 1
)

for /R "%SEARCH_DIR%" %%F in (*) do (
    if exist "%%F" if %%~zF GTR 10000000 echo %%F
)
```

Example: Run above batch script (named script.bat in this example) to list all files greater than 10MB in D drive.

```
C:\>script.bat D:
```

<sub>**Source:** [Batch script to find files greater than 10MB in D drive in Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423100/batch-script-to-find-files-greater-than-10mb-in-d-drive-in-windows-xp/3431477#3431477)</sub>

Comment: I wonder what this is about 10MB.. like an austin powers or red drawf  joke..  Like asking a lawyer what happens if a blind man is walking his neighbours dog in a garden of rose bushes, and he finds exactly that subject on page 644 of some book.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a plain and simple PowerShell solution (as an alternative to batch)

```
gci 'C:\yourpath\yourfolder' | % { get-item $_.FullName | ? { $_.length -gt 10mb } }
```

what we're doing here is:

- getting all files inside your Folder with `gci`
- iterate over all files via `foreach-object` alias `%`
- checking the Items File length via `get-item`
- only select the files which are greater than 10mb by a `where-object` alias `?` query.

**Edit:**
To use this command in a Batch file instead of PowerShell itself, you can write:

```
powershell -command "gci 'C:\yourpath\yourfolder' | % { get-item $_.FullName | ? { $_.length -gt 10mb } }"
```

Comment: Hello experts, I am new to this scripting so, might not able to ask or explain exactly. Appreciate bearing me and for above posts. 
What i was doing is that i need to find the files (logs) which are more than 10 mb in a folder and send the mail with the name of the files.
Tricky part: Mail should be send when there is a new file comes there in the folder, So I have to always keep track and differentiate between the old file and new file.
Problem:  I have written following code, and not able to build the logic for mail. 
How can I identify when new file comes and trigger the mail?

Comment: @echo off

set mail_to_list= ****@gmail.com

powershell echo $vari1 = "& gci 'C:\Users\z003mcsd\Desktop\Performance' | % { get-item $_.FullName | ? { $_.length -gt 10mb } }

}

powershell {Send-MailMessage -To "%mail_to_list%" -From 'v**@****.com' -Subject 'Log File more than 100 MB' -Body 'Check log file to know status.....' -SmtpServer 'mail.*****.de'}"

Comment: @Sam I think it would be good to ask a new question about this, because this question here is not a "good question" and it doesn't concern your mail problem

Comment: I have raised a new question. I have written script in powershell and looking forward. appropriate your contribution.